# Google Maps not working in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-google-maps

I am the creator of [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/ng-map).

I´m trying to develop a directive in AngularJS to show a Google Maps. I can show the map, but I want to go one step further. My directive will accept coords or an address. In case the coords are set, it will show a marker with them. However if the coords are not available, then it should try to show a marker using the address and Geocode.

My problem is when I try to run the geocode function inside the directive, this request looks asynchronous and the rest of the code is executed before I get the response.

How can I force to execute this request?

Please see my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QRj6jXQYxSRR3CseavQY?p=preview

```
<div class="span12">

    {{center}}
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="completeAddress" class="input-xxlarge input-height-large" placeholder="Type your business address...">     
    <map id="map_canvas" style="height: 452px; margin-bottom: 20px;"></map> 

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right" style="margin-bottom: inherit" ng-click="setBusinessLocation()">Save</button>  
</div>
```

You can notice, there is a marker in one city (Gijon) (after geocode), but the map is created before with the center in other city (Getafe).

Thanks,
Roberto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issue,

1. From directive, pass `map` to controller for the map access.
2. Create GeoCoder as a service using $q, and $rootScope.$apply for async. processing
3. Use GeoCoder from controller, and if required from your map directive as the form of 
   `GeoCoder(address).then(...)` to show marker when geocode lookup is done

This is the service part.

```
app.service('GeoCoder', function($q, $rootScope) {
    return {
      getLocations : function(address) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        console.log('address', address);
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address }, function (results, status) {
          $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              deferred.resolve(results);
            }
          });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
});
```

and this is function to add marker from address in controller

```
  $scope.addMarkerFromAddress = function() {
    GeoCoder.getLocations($scope.address).then(function(results) {
      var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map, 
        position: latLng
      });
      $scope.map.setCenter(latLng);
    });
  };
```

And finally, this is demo, http://plnkr.co/edit/9gkanMqVZCldZjYZ5oA2?p=preview